Область поиска адресов по одному городу?
Как настроить область поиска маршрутов, только по Москве?


ymaps.ready(init);

  function init() {
    ymaps.geocode('Москва').then(function (res) {
    var myMap0 = new ymaps.Map('map0', {
        center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
        zoom: 12,
        controls: [ //'zoomControl', // Ползунок масштаба
                    //'rulerControl', // Линейка
                    //'trafficControl', // Пробки
                    //'typeSelector', // Переключатель слоев карты
                   // 'fullscreenControl', // Полноэкранный режим
                  ]
      }),
      myRoute,
      routePanelControl = new ymaps.control.RoutePanel({
        options: {
          showHeader: true,
          title: 'Построение маршрута',
          routePanelTypes: {
            taxi: true
          },
          autofocus: false
        }
      });

    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
      type: "taxi"
    });

    var zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({
      options: {
        size: 'small',
        float: 'none',
        position: {
          bottom: 145,
          right: 10
        }
      }
    });

    myMap0.controls.add(routePanelControl).add(zoomControl);
    routePanelControl.routePanel.getRouteAsync().then(function(route) {
      route.model.setParams({
        results: 1
      }, true);
      route.model.events.add('requestsuccess', function() {
        var activeRoute = route.getActiveRoute();
        if (activeRoute) {
          var length = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("distance"),
            length_value = round(length.value / 1000, 2),
            duration = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("duration"),
            durationInTraffic = route.getActiveRoute().properties.get("durationInTraffic"),
            points = route.getWayPoints(),
            lastPoint = points.getLength() - 1,
            from = points.get(0).properties,
            to = points.get(lastPoint).properties;

          var x = document.getElementById("route0");
              x.style.display = "block";
              document.getElementById('distanse0').innerHTML = length_value;
              document.getElementById('tfrom0').innerHTML = from.get("address");
              document.getElementById('tto0').innerHTML = to.get("address");
              document.getElementById('inway0').innerHTML = duration.text;
              document.getElementById('inway_traffic0').innerHTML = durationInTraffic.text;

              document.getElementById('classText0').innerHTML = route.properties.get("taxi").cheapest.classText;
              document.getElementById('minPrice0').innerHTML = route.properties.get("taxi").cheapest.minPrice;
              document.getElementById('tprice0').innerHTML = route.properties.get("taxi").cheapest.price;
              document.getElementById('waitingTime0').innerHTML = round(route.properties.get("taxi").cheapest.waitingTime/60,0);
        }
      });

    });
  });    
}

function round(a, b) {
  b = b || 0;
  return Math.round(a * Math.pow(10, b)) / Math.pow(10, b);
}
#map, #map0 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=1f5abd1f-b3a7-4d50-adce-391eb1b70d74" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <div id="map0" class="lzl"></div>
    <table id="route0" style="display:none;">
            <tr>
                <td><b style="color:#006600">Стоимость поездки.Такси по данному маршруту в городе Ярославль</b></td><td><strong style="color:#FF0000"><span id="tprice0"></span> руб.</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Точка отправления</b></td><td><span id="tfrom0"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Точка прибытие</b></td><td><span id="tto0"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Общая протяжённость пути</b></td><td><span id="distanse0">0</span> км.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Время в пути</b></td><td><span id="inway0"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Время поездки с учетом пробок</b></td><td><span id="inway_traffic0"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Тариф Яндекс.Такси</b></td><td><span id="classText0"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Минимальная цена проезда</b></td><td>от <span id="minPrice0"></span> руб.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Время подачи автомобиля</b></td><td><span id="waitingTime0"></span> мин.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>



